# Styling issue in a Wordpress form

Tags: html, css, wordpress, forms, styles

This is [my form](http://accountabletest.com/job-position-title/)! . Now I have the 'choose file' button and the legend 'no file chosen' on the 'upload resume' row. I need that 'choose file' button to look like it's actual background img and the legend to be removed **but I don't know how to!**

Also, on the previous form row, the border-radius of 'Select Job Posting' does not match the border-radius of the previous form boxes and **I can't change that property either.**

**I'm open to any solution :)**

My actual  CSS code for the 'choose file' button is:

```
input[type="file"] {
background-image: url('http://accountabletest.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/upload1.png')              ;
background: no-repeat;
z-index: 99999999999 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For input try

```
input[type="file"] {
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-clip: border-box;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  background-image: url("http://accountabletest.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/upload1.png") !important;
  background-origin: padding-box;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto auto;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  text-indent: -99999px;
  z-index: 2147483647 !important;
}
```

[image]

For Select try:

```
.dropdown1 {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F8F8F8;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  color: #808080;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 308px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: The key is `color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-indent: -99999px;`

Comment: now the 'browse to file'button works and renders the way I needed (which is awesome, thanks!). I still need the previous 'Job Number One' dropdown button border radius to match the previous text boxes borders. Do you have any ideas?. Thank u  :)

Comment: ,It renders fine in Mozilla but not in Chrome or safari.

Comment: Sorry bro but for this you need search more about it on Google, or wait for me until tomorrow because right now I have work ;) Btw, I advise you to look on Google following my tip above, that way you will learn more.

Comment: If my answer has helped you remember mark it as correct. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This will target only the button itself. Does not work for -moz- ... but works fine for chrome and safari.

Upload file with default style

[file* upload-resume limit:2097152 filetypes:pdf|doc|docx id:upload-file class:upload-file]

it will look like this

[Default Input File Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iJ3O.png)

What will you need is this code(or you can stylize however you want):

```
input[type="file"]::-webkit-file-upload-button {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #ff921e;
    border: none;
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: .05em;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

[Styled Input File Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nfn8.png)

Hope it helps!